# Back button event listener with react-native-image-zoom-viewer

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use the plugin [react-native-image-zoom-viewer](https://github.com/magicwing/react-native-image-zoom-viewer) to display an image preview and I want to  achieve the simple goal of closing the modal when the user clicks the Android back button. However, the handler function `closeModal` is not fired upon clicking.

I already tried to replace `closeModal` by a non-anonymous function but I still got no results. How could I workaround this problem?

Thanks for help!

```
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer'
import { BackHandler, Modal } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)

const closeModal = () => {
  if (isModalVisible) {
    setModalVisible(false)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', closeModal)
  return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', closeModal)
}, [])


// Here is how I call the modal in the jsx
<Modal transparent visible={isModalVisible}>
  <ImageViewer
    enableSwipeDown
    imageUrls={[
      {
        url: picture.url_min,
      },
    ]}
    onSwipeDown={closeModal}
    renderIndicator={() => null}
    saveToLocalByLongPress={false}
  />
</Modal>
```

Comment: the use effect hook is running only one time as you are passing an empty array so technically you are adding and removing the hardwareBackPress's listner and then nothing will happen. So i think you should remove the empty array dependency

Comment: I want to get an equivalent of `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`. If I remove the brackets, `useEffect` will be called everytime the component renders and that's not what I want.

Comment: there is no problem calling the same function every time we render the component this is how `useEffect` works

Comment: I don't understand why my code wouldn't work, can you please elaborate on the problem? Why would it be better to add and remove a listener everytime the component renders ?

Comment: I actually got it solved with onRequestClose...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hopfully this will work on your project, i just add onRequestClose={} inside Modal

> const closeModal = () => {
> if (isModalVisible) {
> setModalVisible(false)
> }
> }

> Modal transparent visible={isModalVisible} onRequestClose={closeModal} >

and put your close function to onRequestClose={}

Answer (score -1):

Change

> onSwipeDown={closeModal}

to

> onSwipeDown={() => closeModal() }